# Magento 2: How to delete multiple store views?

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view

How do I delete multiple store views in Magento 2?

**I need a path to delete all store views in admin.**

Comment: I cannot see the `**Delete Store View**` button. Can you please explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At admin side you can see store list at Menu: STORES > Settings > All Stores

From here you can delete store view.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `STORES > Settings > All Stores` , click on the name of the store view, at the top of the corner `delete store view` button is there. click and remove the store view.

[image: Delete store view]

Answer (score 1):

The answers are correct. To add sth. more specific if someone asks himself why is delete button not appearing?

Sometimes u cannot see the delete button on store view level, because there is exactly ONE store view entry under the specified store. In this case u have to delete the store and not the store view.

I.E.
1 Store -> 2 Store Views (i.e. de/en) -> Delete Button on store view appears

I.E.
1 Store -> 1 Store Views (i.e. en) -> Delete Button on store view does not appear because of the above explanation

The reason is, that at least u must have one store view left, when all are gone. So your search must go to look how to delete stores and websites and get familiar with your domains and setup.